# String Replace Problem

Tags: c#

I have a string replace problem. I have a result like:

```
"Animal.Active = 1 And Animal.Gender = 2"
```

I want to replace something in this text.

`Animal.Active` part is returned from a database and sometimes it is returned with the `Animal.Gender` part.

When `Animal.Gender` part comes from the database I have to remove this `And Animal.Gender` part.

Also if the string has `Animal.Active = 1`, I have to remove `Animal.Active = 1 And` part. Note the `And`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give some code? That way we can be more of help I guess.

Comment: Do you need to remove the entire "statement", that is, do you want to remove just "And Animal.Gender" or do you want to remove "And Animal.Gender = #". In short, do you want to remove the value that is returned, or just the labels for that value?

Comment: I want to remove And Animal.Gender = # part

Comment: Another question, are you trying to remove *just* the "And" from "Animal.Active = 1 And", if it exists?

Comment: I want to remove when 'Animal.Gender' come from database I have to remove And 'Animal.Gender = 2'. If 'Animal.Active' comes I have to remove 'Animal.Active = 1 And' part

Comment: I'm sorry, your requirement is very confusing as far as I can tell. It *sounds* as if you're saying if any part comes, you want to remove it. But I cannot imagine that is true. Can you edit your question so that you have each possible input you expect, and what you would like to do to that input to change it. For example, if you see "Hello There And Animal.Gender = 2" you would like to see "Hello There" as a result, correct? Can you give more concrete examples so that we may help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a regular expression (regex) to replace this, then, since you want to match a number.

```
  string pattern = "And Animal\.Gender\s*=\s*[0-9]+";
  string replacement = "";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Will work to replace `"And Animal.Gender = #"` with zero or more white spaces between the `=` sign.

You can do a similar replacement for the second request, with Animal.Active.

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is a very specific solution that will undoubtedly become more complicated as you add more conditions, but here goes:

```
dbReturn =
    dbReturn.Replace("And Animal.Gender","").Replace("Animal.Active = 1","");
```